# Is there any way to get data from blockchain of tendermint API

Tags: blockchain, tendermint

Is there any way to get data from blockchain of tendermint API?
[tendermint](https://tendermint.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. What data are you looking for? If you run the node with default settings and go to `localhost:46657/` you see a list of end points.

If you want a block, try `localhost:46657/block?height=42`

Answer (score 0):

The port number 46657 did not work for me, then I tried printing tendermint port and tried hitting `http://localhost:57943/block?height=99`.

Where 99 was the height of my 1st block in the blockchain

57943 is my tendermint port.

So may be it is taking port number dynamically.

Comment: And I am using Lotion upon tendermint.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to access blockchain data from tendermint is using rpc endpoint.The rpc endpoint port can be configured in config.toml file.When you access the endpoint you can see various endpoints few which require arguments and few which don't.The default port was changed from 46657 to 266657 in later versions.